# Dynamically register JAX RS service classes

Tags: jax-rs

Is it possible to register and unregister JAX RS service classes dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

In Apache CXF is posible register an endpoint dynamically.

```
CXFNonSpringJAXRSServlet cxf = new CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet();

...

ServletHolder servlet = new ServletHolder(cxf);
servlet.setInitParameter("javax.ws.rs.Application", "com.acme.MyServiceImpl");
servlet.setName("services");
servlet.setForcedPath("services");
root.addServlet(servlet, "/*");
```

See more:

- [JAX-RS : Services Configuration - Attaching JAXRS endpoints to an existing Jetty server](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jaxrs-services-configuration.html#JAXRSServicesConfiguration-AttachingJAXRSendpointstoanexistingJettyserver)